# A problem occurred evaluating root project

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Could not find method implementation() for arguments [org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

jdk 17

i tried may ways but it didnt help